# How to get volume from mic input on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I have code capturing mic input, and it works fine (I can playback, etc..). My question is, how can I tell how "loud" the input was at a given point, for example, if someone was whispering into the microphone or yelling? Can that be done with the current XNA audio API?